# Elastic search Groovy script in not working with date

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am using groovy script to apply filter on elastic search result. 
Below is the script:

```
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "hour >= '08:50' && hour < '09:00'",
              "params": {
                "hour": "new Date(doc['timestamp'].value).format('hh:mm')"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Below script returns Zero results, now when I change above script to as below:

```
       {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "new Date(doc['@timestamp'].value).format('hh:mm') >= '08:50' && new Date(doc['@timestamp'].value).format('hh:mm') < '09:00'"
            }
          }
        }
```

Now I get the correct results.
So In my opinion, both ways the scripts are same, then why the above script is not giving the correct results.

Thanks.

Comment: The parameters cannot contain groovy code, only static data such as strings or primitive numbers

Comment: ohh, Is that so ? Do you have any reference to it ? I just want to be confirm about it. here, If I use  secong script then the value "new Date(doc['@timestamp'].value).format('hh:mm')" will be computed two times, So I want to avoid the extra computation.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html

Comment: You can assign `new Date(doc['@timestamp'].value)` to a variable inside your script and use that variable twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

```
    {
      "script": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "def hour = new Date(doc['timestamp'].value).format('hh:mm'); hour >= '08:50' && hour < '09:00'"
        }
      }
    }
```

Parameters cannot contain Groovy code, only static String or numeric data.

Comment: Were you able to try this out?